# How to import a variable from an object in other file?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I just found this problem while training my OOP "skills", new to python also ...

I have this:

```
class Obj_one:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj_one_var = 0
    def start(self):
        pass
    .
    .
    .
```

How do I import my "self.obj_one_var" to another object in other file in same directory ?

What I want:

```
class Obj_two:
    def __init__(self):
        obj_one_var
    def using_var(self):
        metrics = obj_one_var + 5

    .
    .
    .
```

**What I've tried:**

**1)** from my_file import Obj_one

----**1.1)** *and use Obj_one.obj_one_var in Obj_two **init** but it gave some error*

**2)** from my_file import *

----and use it like above(in 1.1) but returned some error again*

Comment: What is `Obj_two` trying to do?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it should get variables from Obj_one and combine with it's equivalent variables to do some math operations.

Comment: So... it should "be" an `Obj_one` but with more functionality?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams they have different functions, Obj_one is intended to collect "my data" and Obj_two "someone else data" to do some math stuff and store the result.